# Difference between LM339D and LM339N

Tags: comparator

Im trying to understand different comparators. What is the difference between different LM339 ICs, especially between LM339D and LM339N?

Comment: A quick assessment of [this](http://www.ti.com/general/docs/lit/getliterature.tsp?literatureNumber=slcs006s) datasheet reveals that, at least to first order, the D and the N variety differ in available packages.

Comment: Guess I should have put this ^ as an answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A "D" suffix means that the package is a [SOIC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_Outline_Integrated_Circuit), whereas a "N" suffix means [PDIP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_in-line_package). Note that different vendors may use different suffixes for the package, but both D and N are very common.